# How to save a screenshot of a text file in java

Tags: java, file, screenshot

I need to do this school project where I would take in a text file, convert it to a pdf file (but also format the text so there are different fonts, colors, etc). I thought it would be a cool addon to my project if I were to make a window that would show a visual of how the text file looked before the conversion, and how the pdf file looked after the conversion. I searched up how to take screenshots using java and I was able to find this code snippet.

```
BufferedImage image = new Robot().createScreenCapture(new Rectangle(Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize()));
ImageIO.write(image, "png", new File("/screenshot.png"));
```

However, this would only take a screenshot of the screen in its current state. Is there any way that the java program would be able to take a screenshot of the text file I had, and the pdf file I created afterwards without these two files already being opened and displayed on the screen?

Comment: It's not really a "screenshot" if it's not open on the screen...it sounds like you want to look for some library to "print" a PDF to a Java image.

Comment: Why Screen shot ? Why not you put files ?